# why are c++ methods containing enums causing AccessViolationExceptions in SWIG/C#?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, swig

I am using SWIG to generate a wrapper to a native 32 bit c++ dll. SWIG produces a C++ wrapper file and a lot of generated C# code, this is compiled up into a dll (both C++/CLI and C# projects built as x86) and the resulting functions are callable through C# fine, except those that contain enums. An example:

SWIG generated interface_wrap.cxx file:

```
SWIGEXPORT int SWIGSTDCALL CSharp_myMethod(long jarg1, long jarg2, void * jarg3, void * jarg4) {
int jresult ;
long arg1 ;
long arg2 ;
myEnum arg3 ;
double *arg4 = 0 ;
myEnum const *argp3 ;
int result;

arg1 = (long)jarg1; 
arg2 = (long)jarg2; 
argp3 = (myEnum *)jarg3; 
if (!argp3) {
SWIG_CSharpSetPendingExceptionArgument(SWIG_CSharpArgumentNullException, "Attempt to dereference null myEnum const", 0);
return 0;
}
arg3 = *argp3; 
arg4 = (double *)jarg4;
if (!arg4) {
SWIG_CSharpSetPendingExceptionArgument(SWIG_CSharpArgumentNullException, "double & type is null", 0);
return 0;
} 
result = (int)myMethod(arg1,arg2,arg3,*arg4);
jresult = result; 
return jresult;
}
```

C# extern function delegate definition:

```
[global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ProjectWrapper", EntryPoint="CSharp_myMethod")]
public static extern int myMethod(int jarg1, int jarg2, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]myEnum jarg3, out double jarg4);
```

Interface.i file extract:

```
%module ProjectWrapper
%{
#include "myEnumDefinition.h"
%}

%include "enums.swg"

// %typemap(csbase) myEnum "short" // is something like this needed??

%typemap(cstype, out="myEnum") myEnum&, const myEnum& "ref myEnum"
%typemap(cstype, out="myEnum") myEnum, const myEnum "myEnum"
%typemap(imtype, inattributes="[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]", outattributes="[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]", out="myEnum") myEnum&, const myEnum& "ref myEnum"
%typemap(imtype, inattributes="[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]", outattributes="[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]") myEnum, const myEnum "myEnum"
%typemap(csin) myEnum&, const myEnum& "ref $csinput"
%typemap(csin) myEnum, const myEnum "$csinput"

int myMethod(const long start,const long end,const myEnum enumvalue, double& result);
```

C# definition of enum:

```
public enum myEnum {
  myEnum_value1,
  myEnum_value2,
  myEnum_value3
}
```

C++ definition of enum (from myEnumDefinition.h)

```
enum myEnum
{
  myEnum_value1,
  myEnum_value2,
  myEnum_value3
};
```

When it gets to the point of calling the C# myMethod extern delegate, it is throwing an AccessViolationException every time. If I try to call other methods without any enums as parameters, it works fine.

I don't understand what is wrong here. I have tried to `MarshalAs` the enum in different ways but I can't manage to avoid this exception being thrown. Am I missing something in the SWIG interface file when generating the wrapper?

Comment: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html  The bullet-ed items talk about it.

Comment: Please can you be more specific on which bullet points?

Comment: I think this is the section you need 18.4.2 C# exception example using %exception

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but afraid I could not see the relevance of the section you pointed me to. The accepted answer resolved my problem instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Swig is expecting a pointer to the enum value, according to this line:

```
argp3 = (myEnum *)jarg3;
```

It looks like the C++ method is expecting a `myEnum*` value in its third argument. So you should probably pass your enum argument as a ref:

```
public static extern int myMethod(int jarg1, int jarg2, ref myEnum jarg3, out double jarg4);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was indeed the problem and passing the enum by ref solved it! In case any others run into this, I tried to use the `%val` keyword in SWIG for my enums but this did not work and may be deprecated. In the end I changed just the `%typemap(imtype)` line to be `"ref myEnum"`, this passed the enum by reference but kept everything else the same.